# Redirect da página de login para Recover password?

Tags: asp.net, controles

Estou a fazer uma aplicação em *ASP .net* em que estou a fazer o login com controladores. No entanto na página de login quando clico no hyperlink para fazer recover password o controle não sai da página de login e não sou redirecionado para a página de recover password. Se eu vir o URL ele muda o url para *recoverpassword.aspx* mas a página de recover não aparece e não saio da página de login.
Alguém me pode ajudar a perceber porquê?
Obrigado.

Código na pagina *default.aspx*:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
        }
        else if (this.Page.User.IsInRole("Saba") || this.Page.User.IsInRole("CorpAdmin") )
        {
            //Server.Transfer("Report/ListSabaReports.aspx", true);
            Response.Redirect("~/Report/ListSabaReports.aspx");
        }
        else if (this.Page.User.IsInRole("SumTotal"))
        {
            //Server.Transfer("Report/ListSumTotalReports.aspx", true);
            Response.Redirect("~/Report/ListSumTotalReports.aspx");
        }
        else if (this.Page.User.IsInRole("X-Domain"))
        {
            //Server.Transfer("Report/ListSabaReports.aspx", true);
            Response.Redirect("~/Report/ListSabaReports.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Código no web config:

```
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting"
      assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </controls>
</pages>
```

EU QUERIA ERA QUE AO APARECER A PÁGINA DE LOGIN EU TENHO LÁ UM HYPERLINK COM O TEXTO RECOVERPASSWORD E QUERIA SER REDIRECIONADO PARA ESSA PÁGINA MAS NÃO CONSIGO FICA SEMPRE NA PAGINA DE LOGIN.
ALGUÉM ME AJUDA?

Comment: Poderia postar parte do seu controller onde você faz essa parte de login para que a gente possa olhar? Facilitaria muito na sua dúvida.

Answer (score 1):

As causas podem ser várias:

Se um controlador ou método estiver decorado com a anotação de autorização [Authorize]o sistema redireciona para a pagina de login.

Eu colocaria um breakpoint no controlador e fazer o debug para perceber que código é executado.

Edit:

```
if (!this.Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
    }
```

O código acima diz que se o utilizador não estiver autenticado ele é redirecionado para a página de login.

Normalmente o link para recuperar password está disponível para utilizadores que **não** fizeram o login, porque caso o tenham feito, utilizariam a opção alterar password, certo?

ora se o utilizador ao clicar em recuperar password **ainda não está autenticado** o codigo acima é executado e é sempre redirecionado para a pagina de login!

Comment: e o que você alteraria para puder ser redirecionado para a página de recover password?

Comment: Tal como o código está o utilizador tem de estar autenticado para poder sair da pagina de login. Remove esse código. Na aplicação onde pretendas obrigar autorização coloca [authorize] com data annotations.

Comment: e o authorize funciona igualmente ao redirecttologin()? ou é menos seguro?

Comment: Sim, Nas classes e/ou métodos decorados com o authorize o sistema vai redireccionar para a pagina de login.